# Zerocode Framework for @ParameterizedTest annotation

Tags: testing, junit, performance-testing, load-testing, zerocode

While running performance test on zerocode, I have a method which is annotated with @ParameterizedTest.
But performing load test on it using zerocode Framework it gives an error "Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests". tried using this https://medium.com/@igorvlahek1/load-testing-with-junit-393a83261745

```
method which is annotated with @ParameterizedTest is like this:-
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getData")
    public void aTest(File file) throws IOException, BusinessException {
    
    }


load class is like this:-
  ` @LoadWith("my-load-config.properties")
    @ExtendWith(ParallelLoadExtension.class)
    public class LoadaTest {
        @Test
        @TestMapping(testClass = a.class, testMethod = "aTest")
        public void aTestLoad(){
    
    }
```

is it mandatory to have method annotated with @Test only while performing load test through Zerocode Framework?
please help
thanks in advance`